# C++ get address and size of whole class

Tags: c++, class, assembly

How can i get memory starting address of whole data-class in c++, like asm "lea"? Can i get the size of data-class (including all members), something like sizeof(main)?

```
class main
{  
public:  
    int x;    
    int y;   
    bool xFlag;  
    bool yFlag;  
    ...  
} member1, member2, member3, member4;
```

Comment: In C++ `class` itself has no size at all. You can only get `sizeof(member1)`.

Comment: `sizeof(member1)` and `&member1`. However, I strongly suggest you to change the names to `object1` etc. It seems you are confusing the terms class, object/instance and member.

Comment: Thats just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i get memory starting address of whole data-class in c++, like asm "lea"?

You can't, because when you define a class, it is only helper for the compiler, you do not *allocate storage* at the time (except for static members). To allocate storage you should define an object, than you will be able to get address:

```
main m1; // allocated in data segment
int main() {
    main m2; // allocated on stack

    &m1 ; // take address of m1
    &m2 ; // take address of m2
}
```

There is no such thing as "whole-data class", there is a [Plain Old Data types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType). As of C++11 you'll probably should seek for [StandardLayout types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType) for which "A pointer to an object of standard-layout struct type can be reinterpret_cast to pointer to its first non-static data member"

> Can i get the size of data-class (including all members), something like sizeof(main)?

You can do that with `sizeof(main)`

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
#include <cstdio>

class Main {
  public:
    int x;
    int y;
    bool xFlag;
    bool yFlag;
} member1, member2, member3, member4;

int main() {
  printf("size of Main = %zu\n", sizeof member1);
  printf("size of Main = %zu\n", sizeof(Main));
  printf("address of member2 = %p\n", (void const *) & member2);
}
```

You may get something like the following. The size depends on whether the system is 32-bit or 64-bit, the result below is on a 32-bit system. The address can be any value.

```
size of Main = 12
size of Main = 12
address of member2 = 0x80497d4
```